# OVER ( ORDER BY ) issues

Tags: python, sql, mariadb, window-functions

I would like to write a query to have a cumulative sum and then doing a graph.
But the fact is that the code below is not working well, and I don't know why, i couldn't see any syntax error.

Thanks for any answer provided.

```sql
SELECT
  Datetimedeb,
  Sum(price) OVER (ORDER BY r.idR) as cumul 

FROM res r JOIN activity a ON r.idB=a.idB 

WHERE r.idB='2' AND Datetimedeb > '2010-03-01'
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add a tag for the database engine you're using, and also add the exact error message. Also the python tag appears to be irrelevant. Please remove it or show how it is relevant in the question itself.

Comment: What do you mean "is not working well"?  What result does it give, and how does the result differ from what you want?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? If you're using MySQL, you need version 8.0 to use window functions.

Comment: I should have a column called cumul, with cumulative sum of the rows above, normally.

Comment: Without "window functions", you need totally different code.  And it is messy.  I'm surprised that you need a "cumulative sum" for graphing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said your version of mariadb is 5.5.60. From version 10.2.0 `SUM()` can be used as a [window function](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/sum/).

Comment: Unfortunately, I've tried and get the same issue : #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(ORDER BY Datetimedeb) as cumul FROM res r JOIN activity a ON r.idB=a.idB WHERE ' at line 1

Comment: It seems to be a syntax problem, from OVER i guess because if I remove that part it works well, but I don't have any cumulative sum

Comment: What's your version of mariadb?

Comment: According to my server : 5.5.60

Comment: I modified my answer.

Comment: You can still do a cumulative sum even without a window function, but you need to give a sample of your data.

Comment: Without the sum function ?